# Why isn't this last event code if statement triggering?

Tags: javascript, if-statement

I want to trigger code with different key presses:

```
document.addEventListener("keydown", event => {
    ;(async () => {
        if (event.key === 'b' && event.ctrlKey) {
            alert('1')
        } else if (event.code === 'Space' && event.ctrlKey) {
            alert('2')
        } else if (event.code === 'q' && event.ctrlKey) {
            alert('3')
        }
    })()
})
```

The strange thing is that the last if statement won't trigger. Even if I swap `b` for `q`.

What could be the reason?

There are no errors whatsoever.

https://jsfiddle.net/wn78dc5r/

Comment: Why is the content of the event handler wrapped in a IIFE (that is marked as `async` but doesn't use anything that would require a `Promise` or `await`)?

Comment: Why `event.key === 'b'` but `event.code === 'q'`? The change is quite obvious. Did you already try to use one or the other for all the cases?

Answer (score 4):

Change `code` to `key`

```
else if (event.key === 'q' && event.ctrlKey)
```

Answer (score 1):

It's because `event.code` returns `KeyQ`, in the case `q` is pressed. Try using `event.key` instead.

I would simplify the implementation a bit, as removing IIFE and async, and reusing `event.ctrlKey`:

```js
document.addEventListener("keydown", event => {
  if (!event.ctrlKey) return
  
  if (event.key === 'b') {
    alert('1')
  } else if (event.code === 'Space' ) {
    alert('2')
  } else if (event.key === 'q') {
    alert('3')
  }
})
```

Comment: _"Try using event.key instead"_ - Like in the `if (...)` case which would then cry for a close-vote because of a typo.